# How to know php file in server received a request from a url?

Tags: php, file

I have a PHP file in server. When a user sends the request, that PHP file stores their user values in to database. But my problem is, it is storing values for some particular requests only.

Comment: what particular requests? POST requests?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that a request was received, you can

#### Check the server access log.

No matter how your PHP script is hosted, you should be able to access this. The specifics vary depending on your situation, though.

#### Try logging requests to a text file when the script starts.

If your database insertion somehow fails, this should still work, so it's a possible way to ensure that the script actually gets the request.

Comment: can u tell me , how to write logging requests to a text file, when it get  an insert request

Comment: You could use something like [this](http://www.redips.net/php/write-to-log-file/) and log whatever you need (timestamp, url, get/post, ...).

Comment: hai, thank you for your support. can u tel how to use that code.I have a single php file in my server which contains code to store user values into datastore.  by example can u show me

Answer (score 0):

Your webserver will probably log all connection attempts; find out where those logs are stored (it varies based on which webserver you use, which operating system you run it under, and how you have configured it), and then you can search for the specific URL that you are interested in.